# How do I enable wmode=direct or wmode=gpu

Tags: windows

I have been trying to get a step by step for months now on how to enable wmode=direct.
I have hbo go and whenever I watch a movie the image tears badly. Something about editing the HTML info and SWF files. I am running windows 7 and I could really uses some help! I put in some links to give you an idea of what I am trying to troubleshoot. I know very little about how to write html. (took one class like 5 years ago) I do know how to write a text edit and modify the extension like .cfg or .html.

http://flashvideotrainingsource.com/featured_post/hints-and-tips/quick-tip-fixing-v-sync-tearing-issues-in-flash